# How to numerate (1,2,3...) my DataReader result

Tags: vb.net, streamwriter

so I have this code

```
               Using FileObject As New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
                    Using StreamWriterObj As New StreamWriter(FileObject)
                        connect.Open()
                        Using reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                            Dim FieldCount As Integer = reader.FieldCount - 1
                            Do While reader.Read()
                                StreamWriterObj.Write(reader.Item(0))
                                For i = 1 To FieldCount
                                    StreamWriterObj.Write(" @ ")
                                    StreamWriterObj.Write(reader.Item(i))
                                Next
                                StreamWriterObj.WriteLine()
                            Loop
                        End Using
                        connect.Close()
                    End Using
                End Using
```

which basically sets my results from an SQL query into a StreamWriter Object and exports it as a .txt file.
Here's an example of the result after the select query:

```
+---------------------------------------+
|                Results                |
+---------------------------------------+
+                                       +
| Document No.|   #   |  col 3 |  col 4 |
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+
| 333456      |   0   | "value"| "value"|
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+
| 333456      |   0   | "value"| "value"|
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+
| 462345      |   0   | "value"| "value"|
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+
| 585357      |   0   | "value"| "value"|
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+
```

So my task is to make it in such a way that when i export to the .txt file, inside it will look like this:

```
+---------------------------------------+
|                Results                |
+---------------------------------------+
+                                       +
| Document No.|   #   |  col 3 |  col 4 |
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+
| 333456      |   1   | "value"| "value"|
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+
| 333456      |   2   | "value"| "value"|
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+
| 333456      |   3   | "value"| "value"|
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+
| 462345      |   1   | "value"| "value"|
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+
| 585357      |   1   | "value"| "value"|
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+
| 585357      |   2   | "value"| "value"|
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+
```

or in other words to numerate (next number) the rows based on the document no. (The select query is ordered by Doc. No).

I think a wise solution would be to use a StringBuilder but Im going to need some help with this.

Thank you

Comment: Inside the `For i = 1 To FieldCount` get the Doc Num into a variable, and each time it changes, increment your sequence variable.  I'd probably fill a datatable and use that as a source which would give some other options.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Step 1 - if you haven't done so already, make sure your query orders the results by the document number.

Step 2 - in vb, create a variable named something like numberForThisDocument.  Then as you loop through the query results, assign appropriate values to this variable and include it in your output.

Comment: I would suggest you do it directly with the query. This is something that can be done on most database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

id do it in the actual sql with :-

```
WITH
  q AS
(select query)
,
sequenced as (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Document no. Column] ORDER BY [column name] 
 ) AS sequence_id,
    *
 FROM
    q
)
SELECT
*
FROM
  sequenced
```

Comment: Glad to have helped :)